# How to add multiple assertions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, assertion

I am trying the below code and not sure if I could tell typescript to assume the type from either of the interfaces

```
export interface CellA {
    text: string;
}

export interface CellB {
    date: Date;
}

var cell = {};

const { date, text } = cell as (CellA | CellB);

console.log(date, text);
```

> TS Error: Property 'date' does not exist on type 'CellA |
> CellB'.(2339)

What I am after is to get typescript to assume the destructed variables exist in either of the interfaces. [TS Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYWABsiBBOAbwCg5a5UQYAuOAZximQHMBuKgXypVQkWIhRosuAsSIAhSjToATTKhYARNcD6CqAN0xQ4uEnAC8lfnyrYISdpTirUAGnqh4-CydlxMrHAAFIQk5AA%20MiRyAJQ2dg4QRMAAdEQQXEEuwO4MMHFAA)

Comment: You would need a type guard, because `date` doesn't exist on `CellA`, but you're potentially trying to access it. Same goes for `text` on `CellB`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This smells like an x/y problem...

Comment: @JaredSmith, so I have a React cell component that can be a host to a variety of cell types. Each time is defined as separately and can have varying props

Comment: Then you probably want a discriminated union. I'm on my phone which makes linking difficult, but there's a solid example in the official typescript handbook.

Comment: @JaredSmith cool, i have updated a TS Playground link with the question, feel free to play around, appreciate your time mate, cheers!

Comment: @NidhinJoseph finally got to a computer, added an answer. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `cell` can be of type `CellA` which doesn't have the property `date` (hence the error message you are getting). Note that the vice versa is also true, that `cell` doesn't have the property `text` either.

### Potential Solutions

#### 1. Use an intersection type

If `cell` is supposed be a combination of both `CellA` and `CellB` then you can make `cell` of type `CellA & CellB`. For example:

```
type CellC = CellA & CellB

const cell: CellC = { date: new Date(), text: 'Hello!' }

const { date, text }
console.log(date, text)
```

#### 2. Use type guards: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIQDYYILIN4BQAkJAB5gBcyAzmFKAOYDcBAvgQaJLIiulgCF8xACZxIVACLiILdgRgBXEAjDAA9iGTBq-HAAokWKnBABPAJRUjGbdTSYcwosBj6AhDYvIoEMIqgteAxqCGJXfTAzAAcIdRhkGwA6MjBkdwBeDOQAclp6EAYc719-QORg0OJSgK06RTD5JRU1TTs9AUNHE3MrRMc7B0FnCM9HEr9airgQsJc3dy6sJLFIbRBaUyR45GlICwmyoJmqohry%20saOZtUNLQY-PVRNSHBqJYwqPVwAHyGMAR9UxmEZuHTfD4HHyTcrJVLVGFaZKrK4EBCaajqDAQJIYdQMfQPMBPF4QN76PDIFFUEAQADuuxk%20m8rChAHo2cg8Qx7AAmAAMAoAtABGEVC-kAFgAKiKAMwUEX8ihygDsSSlAA4AFpojFYnHcwmPRzPcBksDvSmpKg5AASjnU7hyyFZ3g5XPx9gdWCdQA)

If you have a value that you need to type check at runtime, you could use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). For example, if you have a variable `cell` whose type you don't know at runtime:

```
const cell = { text: 'Hello!' } // unknown type

function isCellA(obj: any): obj is CellA {
    if(!obj) return false
    if(!obj.text) return false
    if(typeof obj.text !== 'string') return false

    return true
}

if(isCellA(cell)) {
    // at this point the compiler recognizes that cell
    // is of type CellA
    console.log(cell.text)
}
```

If you need to do type checking at runtime, this is probably your best choice. It maintains type safety and helps reduce runtime errors if `cell` really isn't what you expected it to be.

#### 3. Extend another interface

This one is pretty similar to solution #1. If `CellA` and `CellB` are supposed to share some properties then one of them can extend the other, or they can extend a common interface. For example:

```
interface Cell {
    date: Date
}

interface CellC extends Cell {
    text: string
}
```

#### 4: React component composition

If you are having this issue specifically React (as your comment states), you could consider having a separate component that returns the main component for each cell type.
Example:

```
function ACell({ data }: { data: CellA } ) {
    return <Cell>{data.text}<Cell>
}

function BCell({ data }: { data: CellB } ) {
    return <Cell>{data.date.toString()}<Cell>
}

function Cell({ children }: { children: string }) {
    return <p>{children}</p>
}
```

Maybe that doesn't meet your specific use case, but something similar could be helpful in separating logic for each type of cell between components, and sharing common logic with a third `Cell` component, for example.

Comment: Thanks mate, the intersection thing worked, and I am happy with the approach.

Comment: Happy to hear! TypeScript can be hard to use sometimes, but it is such a powerful language.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it is making the assumption that `cell` has both `date` and `text` on it.  But then when you assign `cell` as either a `CellA` or `CellB` type, typescript will complain because each type is missing one of those properties.

Can you just assign optional properties?  Like this:

```js
interface CellType {
  date?: Date,
  text?: string
}

const { date, text } = cell as CellType
```

Or if you really want to force a `cell` to strictly be one of these types, I would do it when you define the variable:

```js
interface CellA {
  text: string;
}

interface CellB {
  date: Date;
}

type CellType = CellA | CellB

const cell: CellType = { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, but still shows error. [check here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYWABsiBBOAbwCgBIVEGALjgGcYpkBzAbioF8qVUJFiIUaLLgLEiAIUq0AJplTMAIiuC8BVGAE8weQiQAqBvAF5pJcgB9rcwQDdMUOLhJwrFPryrYIJDZKOGVUABo4eng+L3cZOEwWBzNDPwCgiCJgADoiCE4ACjDgSOiASm4gA)

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible for you, you can extend the interfaces to accept any other value. For example:

```
export interface CellA {
    text?: string;
    [index: string]: any;
}

export interface CellB {
    date?: Date;
    [index: string]: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally where you want to switch your control flow on the type of an argument/variable in Typescript you'll want to use a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions):

```
interface CellA {
  text: string,
  kind: "CellA",
}

interface CellB {
  date: Date,
  kind: "CellB",
}

type Cell = CellA | CellB;

function takesACell(cell: Cell) {
  switch(cell.kind) {
    case "CellA":
      console.log("Got an A");
      cell.text; // no type error
      break;
    case "CellB":
      console.log("Got a B");
      cell.date; // no type error
      break;
  }
}
```

The compiler understands this pattern to mean that you are dispatching based on the runtime type but it will still provide compile-time type safety in that you can't just pass a non-conforming value.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIQDYYILIN4CwAUMqWZAB5gBcyAzmFKAOYA0xZZA1qACa0AidFmwD2JMgF8OZGaVCRYiFMIwAhfHLK84kWgBFdEcZ1I8Q-ZEMzqxW6RNJawATwAOKm8gC8aG7gAfPyw1AG4tLRgAVxAEMGAAexBkMDguCDpsVQAKJCxaVQBKTUcyOgB3YDAEAAtcmwA6c15iwlLOBDg6FGsRAWotU2QEJLoEjAgGjATmbIEAcQSwZDhk0ULw9tM8jAbKMFDkAHoj5BAElPcUaCgEqEHTACMoCDTNodJO7qtVNX6HjqjcaTaazBZLFbIP4bAFkHYNHSQQ4nM4XVweZA3O6w0jPV5cd6mBycBxAA)